# IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008 R2 - Size limit of request

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, iis-7.5

Is there any size limit for a request that can be handled by IIS? How to disable or increase that limit?

I read somewhere that this limit is 16K, but i am not sure about that or how to disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable it but you can override it in your web.config. It is set in the machine.config that get's shared between all of your files.

Comment: Can you post a sample plz?

Comment: Is that what i need to do?

    <system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1000000" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>

Comment: hi yeah that sounds about right. You use something diff for older .net with httpruntime. Sorry I didn't put an example I was going to then had meeting.